# Change TextArea Text When String Variable Changes TornadoFX

Tags: kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

I have a controller with a string variable, and I would like the text value of a TextArea to change when the controller's string variable changes.

```
class MyView: View() {
...
   button("Run Test").action {
      runAsync {
          for(test in testList){
              controller.updateText = "running" + test.name
              run(test)
          }
      }    
   }
...
   scriptRanArea = textarea {
      text = controller.updateText
   }
...
}
```

Comment: I don't speak Kotlin, but in JavaFX you can represent the string as a `StringProperty`, and either register a listener with it which changes the text in the text area, or bind the text in the text area to it, depending on exactly what you want to do. Note that, since you appear to be using background threads here, that with that approach you should ensure you update the `StringProperty` on the FX Application thread (in JavaFX you do this by wrapping the call that updates the property in `Platform.runLater(...)`).

Comment: That was a huge help, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest way I know how to accomplish this, but I don't really know which design pattern you want to use:

```
class MyView: View() {
   val controller: MyController by inject()

   override val root = vbox {
      textarea(controller.myTextProperty)
   }
}

class MyController: Controller() {
   val myTextProperty = SimpleStringProperty()
}
```

The inject method automatically finds the controller within the TornadoFX Scope, or creates one if not found, when it is first referenced. The TornadoFX text area builder function binds the string property from the controller to the TextArea when it is passed in as a param. Keep in mind though, writing in the text area will now automatically change the value in the controller's property and vice versa. If you don't want that functionality, you will have to update your question to be more specific to your needs.